# Baxter's Downfall

Tags: dogs, training

So we've recently become the new parents of a 7 month old American Bulldog. We are his second home adopting him at 6 months of age. His previous owners kept him out side with no training or interaction. Were not positive if there was abuse but neglect has been very clear through his behavior. Baxter is super smart and loving and within the span of 2/3 weeks was potty trained. 
 Or so we thought.
In the last 2 days he has had about 6 'accidents' in the house. He has had accidents before, we expected that, these just seem deliberate. They always happen when we are busy or when we are relaxing. I am home most of the day, he gets plenty of exercise 1 or 2 walks a day with fetch inside, plenty of attention from both of us and plenty of chew toys. We originally thought he might have a UTI and that he couldn't help it, but its seems as though he chooses when and when not to hold it. We've tried giving him water only at meal times and sticking to the schedule but he still would have 'attention potty tantrums' and I'm wondering is he too young to start marking territory or not? We need a new game plan any advice or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you take him to the vet to check for a UTI?

Comment: We have more than [80 questions with answers about toilet training training dogs](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dogs+toilet-training) have you looked to see if any of them address your questions.